# is there a way to change TextOverflow.Ellipsis or maxLines, dynamically depending on the view size?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-compose-textfield

is there a way to use overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis dynamically depending on the view size?

I am trying to implement this screen that I designed in Figma

[image]

my problem is with the More Information Section.
I used Text object with the attribute maxLines = 5  with TextOverflow.Ellipsis attribute
in Pixel 3a XL the view is correct but on smaller phones
the maxLines need to be smaller like 3. see the example, please

small phone problem

[image]

bigger phone

[image]

Relevant code

```
@Composable
fun ProfileScreen() {

        MoreInfo("Amit Segal is a journalist and a news anchor. He is the host of the N12 news channel. He is a very popular journalist. Amit Yitzchak Segal[1] (born Biz in Nisan 5, 1982, April 10, 1982) is an Israeli journalist, and radio and television personality. Serves as the political commentator of the news company and a political columnist in the \"Yediot Aharonot\" newspaper. One of the most influential journalists in Israel[2]. Presents Meet the Press on Channel 12 together with Ben Caspit.")

    
}

@Composable
fun MoreInfo(information_param: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Column(modifier = modifier.padding(start = 26.dp , end = 26.dp)) {
        Text(
            text = "More information",
            color = Color.Black,
            fontSize = 36.sp,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
        )

        Text(
            text = information_param,
            fontSize = 20.sp,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Normal,
            color = Color.Black,
            maxLines = 5,
            overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
        )
    }
}
```

I want to take the opportunity that I already ask something related. Is there a possibility that when the text reaches the end of the page it will change its opacity so that it slowly disappears downwards instead of the ellipsis

Comment: Using the heightIn modifier instead of maxLines is an option?

Comment: i will try in a minute and tell you if it worked... i can use anything I want

Comment: it is good enough for me thanks!